# How can I block connections to my router page?

Tags: network, router

What I want is, that for example, all my home computers can have access to the page of configuration of my router, but the rest cannot have access to it. With the word "rest" I mean to people that could have hacked my wi-fi password and can access to the configuration page of my router and can harm it with some bad configurations. I'm going to explain this more clearly: I want that my home computers have access to internet (I dont want to block that), what I want is to block the ACCESS TO THE WEB PAGE of my router, the one that starts 192.168.1.x (gateway), that web page. I thought of a firewall, but I dont know how to configure it properly, or if you can bring me other options to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is off-topic here - you might try at Superuser.com, but expect you're answer to be closed there as well if you don't provide a lot more information about your device.

Comment: This sounds like an [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info). Why is password-protecting your router not a sufficient way? Why is using proper wifi encryption not sufficient? Your idea is "if I have random people in my house, they should not be able to go in the kitchen." - if they got into your house, they know how to lockpick. So… you already lost that game in the first place.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser is right. If they're already on your internal home network you've lost. Your router isn't valuable and I am willing to bet you have added security controls to stop ARP poisoning so either way they can steal your traffic and infect vulnerable devices. Pick a good encryption scheme (WPA2 minimum with a non-raw dictionary password.

Comment: @SDsolar I'm really interested in how you think you can control the hosts file of an attacker - and how this would help with direct connections on IPs. I'm fairly sure your answer would have been wrong and would have shown a lack of understanding.

Comment: By closing this it simply leaves behind a stub that is meaningless - no new information was added.  Agree or disagree with the answer, sure, but why not take an action that adds to the database instead of leaving it cluttered with useless detritus?

Comment: An attacker inside the network is a much bigger concern than merely letting them get to the router login page.  And it is trivial to block that page from outside.  In a home network it would be easy.  In a corporate network it could be done by group policy.